# use multiple phrases in trigger phrases with Recognizer -Regular expression

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

How I can set multiple phrases in trigger phrases for recognizer type -Regular expression?
If I set  *menu,service* for example it uses as one phrase. May be exist delimiter for separate phrases? I don't want to use Luis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regular Expression recognizer will accept complex regex expressions. If you want to trigger the same action based on the entry of either the word menu or service, you would create a regex that uses the OR character `|`. You can look up regex guides (something like [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/learn-regex/) perhaps?) and generators online that will help you put together a regex expression appropriate to each situation.